# Connection between spark program and tableau

Tags: apache-spark, tableau-api

We are trying to build a scenario where based on some selection parameters in a 
reporting tool (lets say tableau) a spark program needs to be executed which performs some market basket analysis on a data set against the selection parameters. The result from the program then needs to be displayed in reporting tool.

We are not able figure out how to trigger the spark program once the user enters
selection parameters in the reporting tool (basically the linkage between reporting tool and spark program). Any pointers in this regard would help a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: You wanted the result should be executed from spark for tableau ?So that you will get performance benefit

Comment: Yes, Indrajeet. And it requires some processing to be done in spark, thus the spark code needs to be triggered from tableau

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the steps to connect [Spark sql with Tableau](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_sparksql.html) . If you wanted to do the pre processing then you have to do it in source side . 
Example Take an example of source `hive` with `Tableau`. Then you have to create the view or data massaging in `Hive` side.

Comment: I don't have to connect spark sql with Tableau. I need to somehow trigger a spark program written in scala, from Tableau. I was checking if it is possible.

Comment: is there any option in table to write the code ? i really doubt on this . Each and every programming language has been given the integrated package with this . But if you wanted to do it using code then you can look for the python Tabpy https://github.com/tableau/TabPy

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tableau Server, you can use the Tableau JavaScript API to call a function you write when the user makes a selection. The API also has functions your code can call to refresh or display a viz.